# Fastening the generation of data sequence into array using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, list-comprehension

I have the following code for making the sequences of the dataframe, which has loaded the csv data of rains ratios.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import sklearn
import sklearn.preprocessing
seq_len  = 1100

def load_data(df_, seq_len):
    data_raw = df_.values # convert to numpy array
    data = []
    data = np.array([data_raw[index: index + seq_len] for index in range(len(data_raw) - (seq_len+1))])
    print(data.shape)

df = pd.read_csv("data.csv",index_col = 0)
temp = df.copy()
temp = normalize_data(temp)
load_data(df_, seq_len)temp
```

When I ran the function `load_data(df_, seq_len)temp`, I have to wait a lot of time. I am not understanding whether it is the issue of the `seq_len`.

Here is the attached dataset:  [data.csv](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nucUxpv4PhJ2LzoUYlLTXiqOcOlwQuSi/view?usp=sharing)

Please help me make it faster. It may happen that in future I may have a bigger data. But if this one becomes faster I need not have to worry for the future data.
**EDITED: ** As per  @ParitoshSingh Comment.. Here is the part of the dataset. But do not consider this is the data. It is just a part of bigger data:

```
,rains_ratio_2013,rains_ratio_2014
0,1.12148,1.1216
1,1.12141,1.12162
2,1.12142,1.12163
3,1.12148,1.1216
4,1.12143,1.12165
5,1.12141,1.12161
6,1.1213799999999998,1.12161
7,1.1214,1.12158
8,1.1214,1.12158
9,1.12141,1.12158
10,1.12141,1.12161
11,1.12144,1.1215899999999999
12,1.12141,1.12162
13,1.12141,1.12161
14,1.12143,1.12161
15,1.12143,1.1216899999999999
16,1.12143,1.12173
17,1.12143,1.12178
18,1.1214600000000001,1.12179
19,1.12148,1.12174
20,1.12148,1.1217
21,1.12148,1.12174
22,1.12148,1.1217
23,1.12145,1.1217
24,1.12145,1.1217
25,1.12148,1.1217
26,1.1214899999999999,1.1217
27,1.1214899999999999,1.1216899999999999
28,1.12143,1.1216899999999999
29,1.12143,1.1216899999999999
30,1.12144,1.1216899999999999
```

Comment: @ParitoshSingh I guess I already have provided everything. The issue is with the data I have attached with the question. You can see it and it will work when you run the above code. It takes lot of time.

Comment: @Adam.Er8 No, because `index` increments one by one, so each entry far away from boundaries is copied `seq_len` times. OP, what are you using `data` for later on? If you just compute a rolling average (wild guess), there are better ways to do it.

Comment: @Leporello true, I didn't notice it, sorry.

Comment: @JafferWilson minimal data/example can help us recreate the issue easier from sample inputs. I personally cannot work with a data dump linked to google drive which is blocked here, but i wouldn't wish to work with the data dump in the first place either. It also helps to not have extra functions in the code such as `normalize_data` which has nothing to do with your question here.

Comment: @ParitoshSingh Thank you for the reply. If I share the part of data here, it will not be helpful. It may help in getting the solution but not what I am looking for. Hence, I have to paste the link of the data itself. If it is blocked then I will give a part of data here instead. But you have to consider it as big data.

Comment: @ParitoshSingh Now do you have any solution for faster execution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is essentially a sliding window problem.

One approach is to use vectorization to take the sliding windows over the data faster. Note that If you do not have enough memory to load the final output data, then this may cause issues as well.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
```

Creating some dummy dataframe for ease of use. You should test on your original dataframe.

```
seq_len = 5
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(300).reshape(-1, 3))
print(df.head())
#Output:
    0   1   2
0   0   1   2
1   3   4   5
2   6   7   8
3   9  10  11
4  12  13  14
```

Now, we can create an array for all indexes that we need to use, and use indexing to access all our values in the desired format.

```
def load_data(df_, seq_len):
    data_raw = df_.values # convert to numpy array
    #find total number of rows
    nrows = len(data_raw) - seq_len + 1 #Your code had -(seq_len + 1) for some reason. i am assuming that was just a mistake. If not, correct this accordingly.
    #Now, create an index matrix from the total number of rows.
    data = data_raw[np.arange(nrows)[:,None] + np.arange(seq_len)] 
    print("shape is", data.shape)
    return data

out = load_data(df, seq_len)
#Output: shape is (98, 3, 3)
```

---

EDIT: If you run into memory errors, you can always modify the function to use a generator instead. This way, you take a middle ground between the two scenarios of iterating one by one or consuming too much memory.

```
def load_data_gen(df_, seq_len, chunksize=10):
    data_raw = df_.values # convert to numpy array
    nrows = len(data_raw) - seq_len + 1
    for i in range(0, nrows, chunksize):
        data = data_raw[np.arange(i, min(i+chunksize, nrows))[:,None] + np.arange(seq_len)]
        print("shape is", data.shape)
        yield data

out = load_data_gen(df, seq_len, 15)
test = list(out)
#Output:
shape is (15, 5, 3)
shape is (15, 5, 3)
shape is (15, 5, 3)
shape is (15, 5, 3)
shape is (15, 5, 3)
shape is (15, 5, 3)
shape is (6, 5, 3)
```

Comment: No this is not the answer to my query. Its similar to what I have tried already. Even it takes so much memory that I received `Memory Error`. Not the efficient and fast way.

Comment: @JafferWilson updated, this should do the trick. change chunksize as needed. (Also, you *can* hold the entire data in memory though, right? i am assuming the line `data_raw = df_.values` doesn't blow up for you, yes?)